# Resteasy in seam application is not working

Tags: java, rest, seam, seam2

I get the following error when running tomcat with seam 2.1.2 (old I know), but
I'm trying to get the rest services working with it:

> Apr 18, 2018 7:06:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   listenerStart SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to
>   listener instance of class [org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener]
>   java.lang.VerifyError: (class:
>   org/jboss/seam/resteasy/ResteasyBootstrap_$$_javassist_seam_0, method:
>   _d27sessionWillPassivate signature: (Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpSessionEvent;)V) Illegal use of nonvirtual
>   function call     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getField0(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getField(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.jboss.seam.util.ProxyFactory.setField(ProxyFactory.java:363)  at
>   org.jboss.seam.util.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:352)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.util.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:325)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.util.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:284)
>     at org.jboss.seam.Component.createProxyFactory(Component.java:2426)
>     at org.jboss.seam.Component.getProxyFactory(Component.java:1513)    at
>   org.jboss.seam.Component.wrap(Component.java:1504)    at
>   org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiateJavaBean(Component.java:1442)     at
>   org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiate(Component.java:1359)     at
>   org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2122)     at
>   org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.startup(Contexts.java:304)   at
>   org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.startup(Contexts.java:278)   at
>   org.jboss.seam.contexts.ServletLifecycle.endInitialization(ServletLifecycle.java:113)
>     at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.init(Initialization.java:740)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener.contextInitialized(SeamListener.java:36)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4637)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5099)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)

When I remove the resteasy jars I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/jboss/resteasy/specimpl/UriInfoImpl   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.jboss.seam.Component.initMembers(Component.java:550)  at
>   org.jboss.seam.Component.(Component.java:244)   at
>   org.jboss.seam.Component.(Component.java:205)   at
>   org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.addComponent(Initialization.java:1186)

So I guess I need to know the exact dependencies ?

This is the jars list:

[image: jars list]

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem by downgrade  from tomcat 9 to tomcat 7 and by using the original jars came with the seam package.